# Type 'Observable<Task>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Task[]>'

Tags: angular

I'm working with some legacy code which is a bit messy and don't seem to understand the data flow. Basically I'm trying to make my service return an array of required objects. Each of those objects should be an instance of the corresponding model.

Here is he code for the service:

```
public getTasks(): Observable<Task[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.globals.BASE_URL}/api/v1/tasks`)
      .pipe(
        map(
            (task: Task) => new Task().deserialize(task)
        )
      );
  }
```

Here is what the task model looks like:

```
export class Task implements IDeserializable
{
    public name: string;
    public snn: string;
    public manufacturer: string;

    deserialize(data: any): this
    {
        Object.assign(this, data);
        return this;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the map function doesn't seem to iterate over the array of values and passes the whole array the deserialize method. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your code, what you’re aiming  is to map over the array of tasks returned from your api and call the deserialize function on each one of them.

Assuming that your api does return an array, what you need to do is map that array inside map.

`map((tasks: Task[]) => tasks.map(task => new Task().deserialize(task)))`

Should do the trick

Comment: I've just checked the response using insomnia and the api does return an array of objects.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it works! Apologies for the formatting. Im afk and cant seem to find the character for code markdown

Comment: Well it did work and didn't break anything else in the code. What I don't quite understand is why you have to map it like twice. I mean, if I got an array like so `a = [1, 2, 3]` then I can do something like this: `a.map(i => i * i)` and the result will be `[1, 4, 9]`. But here it doesn't seem to work that way. Why?
I does something to do with the way `pipe` works?

Comment: You might be misunderstanding Array.map and rxjs’ map. Map in rxjs takes the value and processes it based on your logic. It might seem weird at first. I guess you could look at the output stream as the array values. I advise you to read up on rxjs functions to avoid confusing yourself when it comes to array and rxjs differences

Comment: I can’t find the backtick on my iphone keyboard  will change the formatting tomorrow

Comment: Oh I see now, so there's a difference between them, now I understand. I will definitely check it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the server is returning an array of tasks, then you need to iterate over the tasks returned and create your new tasks.

There are a few things you can update in your code to allow the 'intellisense' to help you with this. I have included those and the code I believe you need to accomplish your task below.

```
public getTasks(): Observable<Task[]> {
    return this.http.get<Task[]>(`${this.globals.BASE_URL}/api/v1/tasks`)
      .pipe(
        map(
            (tasks: Task[]) => {
               const newTasks = [];
               tasks.forEach(task => new Task().deserialize(task));
               return newTasks;
        })
      );
  }
```

Comment: Okay, I got the idea I will check it out right now. But even if it works I still don't understand why I need to use forEach here. I thought the map function was supposed to iterate over the array of objects. I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: Map just takes one type of object and returns a different type of object. It doesn't iterate over an array. So in this case you are getting an array of tasks from the server and then 'mapping' that array to an array of UI Tasks.